# I am Making Mock of request But it showing Null?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, moq

[image]

I am Making Mock of Register Agency User But It showing some of its attribute Null.

I am new and I don't understand this.

I am trying to make Mock of Register Agency User that is the model

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task ABCreateActionResult_ReturnsBadRequest_Badrequest()
{
    RegisterAgencyUserRequest mock = new Mock<RegisterAgencyUserRequest>().Object;

    var controller = _accountController.RegisterAgencyUser(mock);

    JsonResult viewResult = (JsonResult)await _accountController.RegisterAgencyUser(mock);

}
```

Here is what I have to Test

```
public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterAgencyUser([FromBody] Models.Request.RegisterAgencyUserRequest request)
{
    JsonContentResult jsonContentResult = new JsonContentResult();
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.InvitationCode) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.InvitationCode))
        return Json(new SharedResponse(AppConstants.ServiceReponses.Error, "A user can't be registered without invitation"));

    var invitationDetails = _inviteRepository.GetInvitaionCodeDetails(request.InvitationCode);

    if (invitationDetails.Type != (int)InviteType.Agency)
    {
        return Json(new SharedResponse(AppConstants.ServiceReponses.Error, "Invalid invitation code"));
    }

    //...
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that you are trying to create a test for?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to mock something that should be just a bag of properties with a public constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only mock dependencies to your class that you are testing. So you don't need to mock a POCO. Just set it up with dummy data like below:

```
var model = new RegisterAgencyUserRequest
{
    Address = "Value1",
    AgencyName = "Value2",
    //...
};
```

and use it like below:

```
var controller = _accountController.RegisterAgencyUser(model);
```

Your dependency for the method is:

```
_inviteRepository.GetInvitaionCodeDetails()
```

so you need to mock the `_inviteRepository` and inject it into the subject controller under test when initializing.

Comment: Yeah i really like this But having some troubles like i want to make lock of real instances like RegisterAgency User request because it is getting from db.I want to make mock instead of passing up dummy data.Could you help me to getting mock of this.

Comment: It should enter dummy data by using mock Because in my Program it check the invitation code that come from DB and then will perform further Action

Comment: @ArslanKhan like I said you need to mock the inviteRepository call that accepts an invitationCode, so that your test method will then not actually execute that code but you have mocked the checking of invitationcode by using mocked responses. Do you understand the concept of a unit test?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup something on the mock, your code just creates an empty object.

```
var mock = new Mock<RegisterAgencyUserRequest>();
mock.Setup(x => x.Address).Returns(() => "some address");
RegisterAgencyUserRequest request = mock.Object;
```

Edit: The answer from Azhar Khorasany explains how it should be done, by not mocking the POCO, but the service/repository that you use in your test.

Comment: Why do you need to mock a POCO? Just create it normally with dummy data.

Comment: Test method Mstest.AccountControllerTests.RegisterAgencyUser_EmptyInvitationCode_Succssed threw exception: 
    System.NotSupportedException: Unsupported expression: x => x.Address
    Non-overridable members (here: RegisterAgencyUserRequest.get_Address) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.

Comment: That approach should work for any public properties on the RegisterAgencyUserRequest object. From your screenshot, it looked like Address was one.

Comment: @PeterDavidsen not for any public property. you would need to ensure that the members to be overridden are virtual. That is why the op got exceptions trying your suggestion. POCOs usually don't have virtual members. It is usually ill-advised to mock classes that have no knock on effects if used as is.